# Wildfly 10 : log which cipher is used for https

Tags: ssl, wildfly, wildfly-10

Before removing/restricting ciphers enabled on https-listener, I would like to identify which cipher is used by clients.

How could I make a log file of that ?

Thank you

Comment: Is Wildfly terminating the SSL connection or do you have something in the front?

Comment: @stdunbar yes wildfly doing the termination so not sure how to get SSL logs